# How to set Matplotlib figure to 100% of available space?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to get a Matplotlib figure to span the entire space available inside a notebook.

So I want to have the figure make use of the space taken up by the red box:

[image]

This code generated the screenshot:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris 
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

iris_data = load_iris() 
join_pd_df = pd.DataFrame( 
  data = np.c_[ 
    iris_data['data'], 
    iris_data['target'], 
  ], 
  columns = iris_data['feature_names'] + ['target'] 
) 

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns 

list_of_features = [ 
  "sepal length (cm)", 
  "sepal width (cm)", 
  "petal length (cm)", 
] 

number_of_charts = 2 
number_of_features = len(list_of_features) 
arbitrarily_large_number_of_inches = 10 # I want to avoid hard-coding this value
fig, axes = plt.subplots( 
  number_of_features, 
  number_of_charts, 
  figsize=(arbitrarily_large_number_of_inches, arbitrarily_large_number_of_inches) 
) 

for iteration, feature in enumerate(list_of_features): 
  sns.regplot(x="target", y=feature, data=join_pd_df, ax=axes[iteration, 0]) 
  sns.boxplot(x=feature, y="target", data=join_pd_df, ax=axes[iteration, 1]) 

plt.subplots_adjust( 
  left = 0.1, 
  right = 0.9, 
  top = 0.9, 
  bottom = 0.1, 
  wspace = .4, 
  hspace = .4, 
)
```

However, I would like to avoid hardcoding `arbitrarily_large_number_of_inches` to `10`, which could change based on my monitor screen size.

Is there something equivalent to HTML's `width=100%`?  Something like the relative units for `subplots_adjust` would work as well.

Thank you for your time

Comment: There's a difference between the actual size of a figure (which is measured in inches) and how much space it would take up in a notebook - and that's side-stepping the question if the notebook would always have the same size. There's no equivalent to the 100% you're suggesting from the matplotlib size, but there may be ways to control how it is displayed in your notebook? Perhaps you could provide some details on how the plot is shown, and what you expect to change from that perspective?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  I've updated the question with a screenshot that can, hopefully, make it easier to understand what I am trying to accomplish.  Thank you again for your time

Comment: Would you expect the charts on the left to expand in width to become about 3.5 wider, in the same configuration? In your notebook, do you have access to the information about the viewport? Can you share a bit more information about what you use to create your notebook, and the code in your notebook - is it just the code you shared?

Comment: I'm using notebooks hosted here: https://community.cloud.databricks.com/login.html

Comment: I would like both columns of charts to grow and fill up the extra space, similar to how web page elements grow with the window size.  I don't know if it's possible to get the viewport information from a notebook.

Comment: I updated the code snippet in the question to include all of the code.  Hope that helps and thank you for your time :)

Comment: in that case maybe i shouldn't have tagged `jupyter-notebook`. i'm not too familiar with databricks, so if their UI is totally different, feel free to untag.

Comment: I would be interested in how to do it for `jupyter-notebook`s as well.  Most of the example code in those notebooks have worked for `databrick` notebooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it is not possible at this time :(